# jQuery: simulate onClick with a specific mouse BUTTON

Tags: jquery

So when using

```
$("#myElement").click(function(){
    //do something
});
```

the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/click/) notes:

> The click event is only triggered after this exact series of events:
>
> - The mouse button is depressed while the pointer is inside the    element.
> - The mouse button is released while the pointer is inside the element.

This works for **BOTH** left and right mousebutton clicks.

Now I want to simulate this with only one specific mouse **button** (*doesn't matter which one, it's just the concept to simulate `click()`*). I know you can use:

```
$("#myElement").mousedown(function(event){
    if(event.button == 0) //leftclick
    else if (event.button == 1) //middleclick
    else if (event.button == 2) //rightclick
}
```

This is all great and well, but note this wouldn't be the same as `click()`. Again from the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/):

> If the user clicks on an element, drags away from it, and releases the
>   button, this is still counted as a mousedown event. This sequence of
>   actions is treated as a "canceling" of the button press in most user
>   interfaces, so it is usually better to use the click event unless we
>   know that the mousedown event is preferable for a particular
>   situation.

Analogous for `mouseup()`. So using one of both is obviously and definitely not the desired result. So how can we achieve the desired result?

Comment: "with only one specific mouse click"... mind sharing what that specific mouse click would be?

Comment: edited, doesn't matter which one, it's just to detect only one and not many. the solution should be analogous to the other buttons as wel.

Comment: "its just to detect only one and not many" ... you mean clicks? click types? please be more specific.

Comment: Look at the title: _"simulate onClick with a specific mouse **button**"_. My question also states: _"This works for **BOTH** left and right mouse clicks. Now I want to simulate this with only one specific mouse click.."_ So the semantic meaning of _"detect only one and not many"_ is 'left mouse button click', 'right mouse button click', 'middle mouse button click', or whatever mouse buttons your mouse has. Since `click()` detects both left and right, I want to be able to detect one of each. Or any other mouse button a mouse has. But for demonstration purposes, left or right should suffice.

Comment: no need to get defensive, there is a reason no one has bothered to answer this question. ill provide a complete answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Checking `event.button` should work for `click` the same as it does for `mousedown`, assuming your handler actually gets called. I can't find a test scenario in which the handler gets called for right-button clicks - for me, they always go directly to menu without giving the javascript a chance to intervene. (And that's the way it should be. web sites monkeying with the user's right-button menu - usually in a vain attempt to "disable view source" - are garbage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your explanation, you have answered your question in the question itself. You cannot simulate (or in jQuery terms, `.trigger()`) a click as a single button. however you can perform the `e.which` detection you were doing for `mousedown` on `click` and it will do exactly what you want.

```
$("#myElement").click(function(e){
    switch(e.which){
        case 1:
            // do left click stuffs
            break;
        case 2:
            // do middle click stuffs
            break;
        case 3:
            // do right click stuffs
            break;
    }
});
```

Or if you only wanted to do an action only when a specific button is clicked and do nothing otherwise:

```
$("#myElement").click(function(e){
    if(e.which === 1){
        // do your stuffs
    }
});
```

Then if you want to simulate it with a different event, just make the action a function:

```
function leftClick($el,e){
    if(e.which === 1){
        // do your magic with $el
    }
}
```

Then you can call it with anything you want

```
$("#myElement").click(function(e){
    leftClick($(this),e);
});

$('.SomethingElse').on('click',function(e){
    leftClick($('#myElement'),e);
});
```

to answer the obvious "why not test the `e.which` before passing to the function? The answer is ... personal coding choice. The way I did it is less verbose and if you call it 30,000 times it will be faster ... but to each their own, either way will work.

Comment: `e.which`, right.. I was using `e.button` the whole time, which wouldn't work for the `click()` event. I thought `e.which` would lead to the same. Anyway, `e.which` seems to do the work. Thanks.